# Volume of hyperbolic submanifold of surface with a boundary component

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a compact surface of genus $k \geq 2$ having a single boundary component. Let $U \subset \text{Int}(\Sigma)$ be an open subset of the interior of $\Sigma$ with a Riemannian metric $g$ on $U$ such that (1) the Gaussian curvature $K$ of $g$ is identically equal to $-1$, (2) the  volume form for $g$ extends to a smooth $2$-form $\omega \in \Omega^2(\Sigma)$ that vanishes on $\Sigma \setminus U$.

I would like to know if the volume of $U$ is bounded above. The bound I have in mind is $2\pi (2k-2)= -2\pi(\chi(\Sigma)+1)$ (i.e. the volume of a closed genus $k$ surface with respect to a Riemannian metric of constant curvature $-1$).

Comment: Item 2 is unclear.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated it.

Comment: It did not help: Formally speaking, every differential 2-form vanishes on a 1-dimensional manifold. You probably meant something else. Also, what exactly do you mean by a Riemannian metric on a manifold with boundary?

Comment: I don't mean the pullback of $\omega$ to the submanifold $\partial \Sigma$ vanishes. I mean that, as a section $\omega \in \Gamma(\bigwedge^2(T^*\Sigma))$, for all $x \in \partial \Sigma$ we have $\omega(x)=0$. Equivalently, for each $x \in \partial \Sigma$, the alternating bilinear map $\omega_x \in \bigwedge^2(T_x^*\Sigma))$ is identically $0$.

Comment: I have updated the question again - take $U$ to be an open subset of the interior of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ok, lastly, when you say "bounded above", do you mean "if $U$ is fixed and $g$ is variable, then the area is bounded above?" This question has the same answer as the old one I answered today and the technique is very similar, just one has to be a bit more careful constructing a form $\omega'$ since the vanishing set is now infinite.